# Why Google datastore doesn't save instance (python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

Good day.
I need to save object of Leader class to datastore. There is server code:

```
def post(self):     # add new user to database
    email = self.request.POST.get('emailReg')
    fullname = self.request.POST.get('fioReg')
    password = self.request.POST.get('passReg')
    role_lead = self.request.POST.getall('roleLeadReg')
    role_org = self.request.POST.getall('roleOrgReg')
    if role_lead:
        command = self.request.POST.get('commandReg')
        territory = self.request.POST.get('territoryReg')
        newLead = Leader(fullname=fullname, command=command, territory=territory, email=email, password=password)
        newLead.put()
        self.response.write(newLead)
```

And Leader model:

```
class Leader(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)                      
    fullname = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    command = db.StringProperty(multiline=False, default=u'Отсутствует')
    territory = db.StringProperty(multiline=False, default=u'Отсутствует')
    password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I am absolutely sure that I get POST-data from request because I looked at variables email, fullname etc. and they aren't empty.

There is one weird fact - fields territory and command always saved to db correctly. But another - don't.
What may be the reason of my trouble?

I looked at official docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_put 
And didn't find any specifity of put() method.